# In fp-ts, does the function that applies an Environment to a Reader have a particular (conceptual) name?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

In a `Reader<E, A>` the `E` parameter represents the environment to read a value of type `A` from.

If I have a reader and an environment and would like to read the value from a reader via `pipe`, one way of doing it is via:

```js
const a = pipe(rdr, I.ap(e))
```

I wonder if the operation `I.ap(e)` has a particular name in the scope of a reader that makes the intend more obvious?

Comment: People won't be able to help if you don't provide more context. What is rdr defined as? What is e? Give a concrete example please.

Comment: What do you mean by "read the value from a reader"? When inside a reader context, you can access the environment `E` by using methods like ask (https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Reader.ts.html#ask).  You can't "read the value" of `A`. The only way to do so is to actually execute the Reader i.e. `myReader(environment)`